# Is there a way to keep huge Java variables in-memory to save up loading time?

Tags: java, memory, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and I am loading a big number of files in memory. Every time I run the app it takes an amount of time to load them.

Is there a way to keep them in the memory between runs?

Comment: No, but you can use some in-memory database that will save your time.

Comment: can you suggest one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep [the loaded files] in the memory between runs?

In a word, no.

The best you could do would be to optimize the load time, or restructure your application so that it didn't need to load all of the files.

Here are suggestions:

- Instead of loading all of the data into the JVM's memory, store it in a conventional or "nosql" database (on disc or in memory<sup>1</sup>)
- Restructure the application / partition the problem so that you don't need everything in memory at the same time.
- Load the files lazily.
- Access the information in the files via memory mapped buffers, and avoid turning it all into heap objects.

None of these ideas will be straightforward.  And I can't predict which (if any) will be effective ... without a lot more information on what you are trying to do.

---

<sup>1 - That is, in memory in a separate database server or servers.  Of course, when you start / restart the in-memory database servers, they have to load the data from disc, but you can have lots of your application JVMs talking to the database, serially or at the same time.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to refactor the application into two smaller applications that talk to each-other via the loopback. One of the applications can be responsible for serving the files and the other one for using them. The application which serves the files can hold in an memory cache of the files up to a certain memory limit, using byte arrays.

You can then restart the application that uses them as many times as you like without having to restart the application that serves (and caches), the files.

You may not even have to split the application into two. **Linux for example does cache files in memory. So tuning your file system cache will help, so that as many of these files are stored in memory as possible.** There are a lot of configuration options to consider. How long do you want the files to reside in the cache? How big are the files relative to the maximum cache size? The answer to the following question sheds some light on this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching

It may also be necessary to double check the JVM implementation that you are using, just to make sure it will not bypass the cache and force a hard-drive read, though I seriously doubt this would happen.